# Difference between regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, expression

I'm trying to work out what the differences are between these two:

```
preg_match('-^[^'.$inv.']+\.?$-' , $name

preg_match('-['.$inv.']-', $name
```

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php. the first one is anchored and inverted with some repeats. the second one isn't.

Comment: My understanding is one should check for $inv in $names, the other should do the same except is the $name ends in full stops ?

Comment: If -^[^a]+\.?$ allows a single dot at the end, how would I change this so it works the same but allows multiple dots (this could get to being a lot of dots) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it easier to exemplify, assume `$inv = 'a'`…

- `-^[^a]+\.?$-` needs to match the whole string, because of the caret and the dollar signs. The string is expected to start with a character other than "a", followed by 0 or more characters that are still not "a"s. The last character in this string, however, can be a dot (hence the question mark after the dot)
- `-[a]-` will match the first "a" in the string and it will stop looking as soon as it finds a match because you're using `preg_match()` and not `preg_match_all()`.

Your first pattern does not make any sense, though, since already `\.` = `[^a]` (translated into English as: a dot is already not an "a")

**[EDIT]** The first pattern can actually mean something when there's a dot in the character class.

Comment: I've accepted this as it's plain English and I understand that :)

Comment: @user1932360 Considering you're using a character class, which is likely to include a dash to indicate a range, I would use some other character for the beginning and end of the pattern (delimiters) to make sure nothing goes wrong. Also, don't forget to escape necessary characters in the character group.

Comment: $inv is an array of characters controlled by us. It's not changeable or upgradable by the user etc.

Comment: The first pattern "doesn't make sense" only in your example definition of `$inv`. What if `$inv = 'a.';`?

Comment: @user1932360 then of course it does. Sorry, I haven't thought of this possibility.

Answer (score 2):

First of, be careful with `$inv`, depending on its content it could be possible to do some injections in the regular expression. To avoid that issue, use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

That said, the first regex will be :

```
^    <-- the given string must begin with
  [    <-- one of those characters
    ^    <-- inverse the accepted characters (instead of accepted characters, the following characters will be those that are not accepted)
    $inv <-- characters
  ]    <-- end of the list of characters (here not accepted characters)
  +    <-- at least one character must be matched, more are accepted
  \.   <-- a '.'
  ?    <-- the previous '.' isn't mandatory
$    <-- the given string must end here
```

If `$inv = 'abc.'` it will match:

- `def`
- `def.`
- `d`
- `d.`

It won't match:

- `.`, because the `.` isn't accepted by the `[^abc.]` group, even though there is `\.?` later, at least one character must be before a `.`
- `de.s`, because the `.` isn't accepted in the `[^abc.]` group, it is only possible to have it at the end of the given string thanks to `\.?`
- `a`
- `deb`
- `testc`
- `teskopkl;;[!@#$b.`, because of the `b`
- an empty string, at least one character must be matched with `'[^'.$inv.']+'`

It could be simplified into `'^[^'.$inv.']+$'` (don't forget the `preg_quote` though)

---

The second one will be:

```
[    <-- one of those characters
  $inv <-- characters
]    <-- end of the list of characters (here accepted characters)
```

If `$inv = 'abc.'` it will match

- any string containing at least one of the letters `a`, `b`, `c` or `.`

It won't match any string which doesn't contain `a`, `b`, `c` or `.`.

Answer (score 0):

The first pattern matches a line containing none of the characters in `$inv`, optionally ending the line with a period.

The second pattern matches anything containing any of the characters in `$inv`.

- `-` is the pattern delimiter, marking the beginning and end of the expression. It can technically be *any* character, but is most often `/`.
- `^` denotes the beginning of the string
- `[ ]` encapsulates a set of characters to be matched
- `[^ ]` encapsulates a set of characters that should *not* be matched, any *other* character is considered to be a match.
- `+` denotes that the previous character or set of characters should be matched one or more times.
- `.` normally matches any character, which is why it is escaped as `\.` here to indicate a literal period character.
- `?` denotes that the previous character should be matched zero or one time.
- `$` denotes the end of a string.

Comment: changing the ? to * will that allow multiple matches of . ?

Comment: @user1932360 `*` matches the previous character zero to infinity times.

Answer (score 0):

In plain English, the first one is looking for an entire line which begins with one or more characters not included with the `$inv` string, and ending with an optional period.

The second one simply tries to match one character as specified by the value for `$inv`.

Answer (score 0):

```
['.$inv.']
```

Lets go with the second one to begin with, since it's the simpler one.

- This simply matches a string containing any single one of the characters contained within the string in the variable `$inv`.
- It could contain anything else before or after that character from `$inv`.

```
^[^'.$inv.']+\.?$
```

Now the second one:

- This matches a string that contains anything *except* the characters in `$inv` (the `^` inside the `[]` is a negative match).
- The match that isn't part of `$inv` must be at the start of the string (the `^` outside the `[]` matches the start of the string).
- The string can contain as many matching characters as it likes (one or more; that's the `+` sign after the `[]`)
- After that, it may optionally have a dot (the `\.?` is an optional dot character).
- And nothing else after that (the `$` matches the end of the string).

Note that in both cases, if `$inv` contains any regex reserved characters, it will fail (or do something unexpected). You should use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to avoid this.

So... uh, they're completely different expressions. Not so much "what's the difference between them" as "what's the same about them". Answer: not much.

Answer (score -1):

The first matches a string from start up to the first occurance of $inv followed by one or zero periods where the string must end.

The second matches a string only containing $inv.

Essentially they are almost the same, except the first allows for a possible . at the end.

Comment: no. you forgot the `[]`. it's matching ANY characters contained in `$inv`. e.g. `/[hello]/` will match `h`a string which contains only an `e`.